# Do Google Photos maintain any other color spaces except sRGB

Tags: color-spaces, srgb, google-photos

Do Google Photos maintain any other color spaces except sRGB?
Does it convert photos to sRGB automatically and save them like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Photos does not "maintain" or "convert" color spaces.  The color space is a property of the image, usually noted in the Exif metadata.  Since Google Photos preserves metadata, color-managed browsers should be able to display images as intended as long as the browser is configured properly.